# Counterexamples for strong laws of large numbers

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability, stochastic-processes

Let $\{\xi_k\}_{k=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of random variables in $L^1(\Omega)$.

We have the following laws of large numbers:

> **Theorem (Strong law of large numbers 1**)
>
> Assume
>
> 1. $\xi_1, \xi_2, ...$ independent
> 2. $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mathbf{Var}(\xi_n)}{n} < \infty$
>
> Then  $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n(\xi_k-\mathbf{E}(\xi_k)) \to 0
>   \text{ a.e.}.$$

How can I prove that the result does not hold if we remove either assumption 1. or assumption 2.?

> **Theorem (Strong law of large numbers 2**)
>
> Assume
>
> 1. $\xi_1, \xi_2, ...$ independent
> 2. $\xi_1, \xi_2, ...$ identically distributed
>
> Then  $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n(\xi_k-\mathbf{E}(\xi_k)) \to 0
>  \text{ a.e.}.$$

How can I prove that the result does not hold if we remove either assumption 1. or assumption 2.? How can I prove that if we remove either assumption 1. or assumption 2. we cannot even conclude that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n(\xi_k-\mathbf{E}(\xi_k)) \to 0$ **in probability**(that is, weak law of large numbers)?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: To show that you can't just drop 1.), consider the case where all $\xi_i$ are the same random variable (as in, exactly identical, not just identically distributed).

Comment: That's right. Thank you.